# Is it possible to use method in the group by method in Linq?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to group by my custom method. For example, if the group id is something, then I want to return 1 or 0 from the method of `GetClientGroup`, then I want to group by the value. But I am getting error such as this.

**Error**

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```
await (from o in _cdsContext.Order
   where o.ClienteleId == clienteleId && o.DeliveryDate >= new DateTime(2020, 06, 29).Date
   && o.DeliveryDate != null
   group o by new
   {
       o.ClienteleId,
       o.DeliveryDate,
       ClientGroup= o.OrderTypeId == 22 ? 259 : GetClientGroup(clienteleId, (int)o.GroupId), 
   }
 into g
 select new { ClienteleId = g.Key.ClienteleId}).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: The error message is clear, `GetClientGroup` custom method can not be translated to SQL. What is that method? BTW ,as error says that you can retrieve data then group it in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get this error at run time, not at compile time. Am I right?

### IEnumerable and IQueryable

You should be aware of the difference between `IEnumerable<...>` and `IQueryable<...>`.

Object that implement `IEnumerable<...>` or `IQueryable<...>` represents the **potentional** to give you an enumerable sequence. Once you've got the sequence, you can ask for the first element, and once you've got this, you can ask for the next element as long as there is an element.

This iterating over the elements is usually done using a `foreach (var element in sequence) {...}`. This translates into the following:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> sequence = ...                          // the potential to get iterator
IEnumerator<MyType> enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();  // get the iterator

while (enumerator.MoveNext())                               // iterate
{                                                           // as long as there are items
     MyType item = enumerator.Current;                      // fetch the item
     ProcessItem(item);                                     // and process it.
}
```

The LINQ methods that don't return `IEnumerable<...>` or `IQueryable<...>`, like `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, `Count`, `Any`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc internally all use `foreach` or `GetEnumerator`

An object that implements `IEnumerable<...>` is meant to be processed by your local process. The object holds everything to be able to iterate, inclusive calls to local methods.

On the other hand, an object that implements `IQueryable<...>`, like your `_cdsContext.Order` is meant to be processed by another process, usually a database management system.

This object holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` is a generic form of the data that you want to query. The `Provider` knows who has to execute the query, and what language is used (usually SQL)

Concatenating LINQ statements won't execute the query, they will only change the Expression. When (deep inside) `GetEnumerator()` is called, the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider`, who will translate it into SQL and execute the query at the DBMS. The fetched data is represented as an iterator to your process, who will repeatedly call `MoveNext()` and `Current`.

### Back to your question

Your `GroupBy` contains a call to a local method. The GroupBy won't execute the query, it will only change the Expression. In the end you do a `ToList`. The Tolist will do a `GetEnumerator()`. The Expression is sent to the Provider who will try to translate it into SQL.

Alas, your provider doesn't know your local method `GetClientGroup`, and thus can't convert it into SQL. In fact, apart from all your local methods, there are also several LINQ methods that can't be translated into SQL. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ methods (LINQ to entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Your compiler doesn't know which methods the provider can translate, so the compiler won't complain. Only at run time, when you do a ToList, the problem is detected.

### How to solve the problem

The problem is in parameter KeySelector of [Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___)

```
Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> keySelector
```

Alas you forgot to write what GetClientGroup does. It seems that it takes the ClienteleId and the GroupId of an Order, and returns an integer that is similar to a ClientGroup.

The most easy would be to replace the call to GetClientGroup with the code that is in that method. **Don't call any other methods**

```
DateTime deliveryLimitDate = new DateTime(2020, 06, 29).Date;
var result = dbContext.Orders
    .Where (order => order.ClienteleId == clienteleId
                  && order.DeliveryDate != null
                  && order.DeliveryDate >= deliveryLimitDate)
    .GroupBy(order => new                                 // Parameter KeySelector
    {
         ClienteleId = order.ClienteleId,
         DeliveryDate = order.DeliveryDate,
         ClientGroup= order.OrderTypeId == 22 ? 259 :
             
                  // formula in GetClientGroup(...)
                  // for example
                  (int)order.GroupId << 16 + order.ClienteleId

         // parameter ResultSelector
         group => new { ClienteleId = group.Key.ClienteleId});
```

Instead of a separate Select, I used the GroupBy overload with a parameter ResultSelector. Your result is a sequence of objects with only one property ClienteleId. Consider to return only a sequence of ClienteleId:

```
         // parameter ResultSelector
         group => group.Key.ClienteleId});
```

Alas, since I don't know your GetClientGroup, I can't give you parameter KeySelector